# App Web Links asking for Chrome TOS despite Firefox being default browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, default-applications, firefox-for-android

Short version:

When I click links in the Reddit Android app, it brings up Chrome. I want it to bring up Firefox, but it doesn't give me the option.

Long version:

I just bought a phone and installed Reddit and Firefox on it. When I click on links in the Reddit web app it brings up Chrome, asking me to accept the *Google Chrome Terms of Service*. But I haven't used Chrome, I've been using Firefox as my default browser.

I've tried to follow [Mozilla's instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/make-firefox-default-browser-android) on setting the default browser on my phone, which includes clicking a `Clear defaults` button, but none of my apps have any defaults to clear. Of my browsers, none has an enabled `Clear defaults` button. I've painstakingly gone through every app in the phone looking for an app with an enabled button (just in case it was hidden in some "com.blah.blah" app) and found none. The app simply never asks me which browser I'd like to use. It may be the Reddit app itself making a false assumption about the browser availability... anyone care to verify? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either uninstall chrome or, if this device came with chrome pre installed you can go to settings>apps, search for chrome and disable it.

Comment: Ah hah! Now I see what's going on. Reddit uses some kind of in-app browser component to display pages and apparently that only uses Chrome. Now the app displays a blank page and I have to click into `options->Open External URL` to see a link. Either way, this answered the question, thanks!